# Error when I call a variable in my PHP file Twilio send messages

Tags: php, html, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I'm configuring Twilio sendnotifications.php file as described on this [website](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/increase-app-downloads-with-mobile-app-distribution-powered-by-twilio.html)

When I launch "php sendnotifications.php" in the terminal with this code, everything works perfectly and I receive my SMS

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'My id';
$token = 'My token';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    'MyPhoneNumber',
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => 'MyTwilioSendingNumber',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => "My message"
    )
);
```

But when i run it like this I have an error:

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'My id';
$token = 'My token';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$phone='MyPhoneNumber';

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    $phone,
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => 'MyTwilioSendingNumber',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => "My message"
    )
);
```

The error is:

```
MacBook-Pro:Test envoi sms accueil Joris$ php sendnotifications.php

Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number 74663 is not a valid phone number. in /Users/Joris/Desktop/Test envoi sms accueil/Twilio/Version.php:85
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Joris/Desktop/Test envoi sms accueil/Twilio/Version.php(219): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...')
#1 /Users/Joris/Desktop/Test envoi sms accueil/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageList.php(69): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Accounts/AC8ec...', Array, Array)
#2 /Users/Joris/Desktop/Test envoi sms accueil/sendnotifications.php(20): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList->create('$phone', Object(Twilio\Values))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /Users/Joris/Desktop/Test envoi sms accueil/Twilio/Version.php on line 85
MacBook-Pro:Test envoi sms accueil Joris$
```

Comment: In order to send a test sms using the Twilio test numbers, you need to make sure you are using your test credentials. From the looks of this code it seems you may be using your actual credentials.

Comment: Alright thanks but I didn't use a sending test number, I used a purchased number. When I try with a test number, I don't have error message but I don't receive anything, is it normal ?

Comment: Oh sorry I saw that it's normal to not receiving messages with test credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-tried with the second code and it's working, I don't know why :D

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'My id';
$token = 'My token';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$phone='MyPhoneNumber';

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    $phone,
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => 'MyTwilioSendingNumber',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => "My message"
    )
);
```